# How can I make a sound play when an item is clicked?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Flappy Bird minigame using the plugin Create Your Own Menus, otherwise known as CYOM.

To play, you click a feather and it goes into another menu showing that it went forward, and so on.

I need it so when the user clicks the feather, it plays a sound.

I've used the command:

```
/playsound entity.experience_orb.pickup master @p
```

And I used the plugin to implement that command into the feather, so when clicked, the sound plays. Problem is, an error message shows:

> Server: Player ThePinoyPlayer is too far away to hear the sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the player is too far to hear the sound , so try instead to use the /execute command

> /execute @p ~ ~ ~ /playsound entity.experience_orb.pickup master @p